# Problemas al publicar web local a través de IIS, no me deja entrar a otras vistas que no sea home

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, iis

Público mi web ASP.NET a través de la opción de carpeta y sistema de archivos en VS 2019.
Ingresamos a esta a través de la IP del PC que aloja está web, logramos entrar al Home de la página, pero al momento de ingresar a unas de las otras vistas me sale un error que dice "Not Connect. Verify your network.", verifique la URL y la identifica correctamente, y carga la barra del menú pero no el contenido de la pagina.
No tengo experiencia realizando este tipo de trabajos, alguna idea de como solucionarlo.